# Soundpool.builder samples no ready

Tags: android, soundpool

I have issue with loading sound samples in soundpool.builder meanwhile in deprecated soundpool all  sound work  perfect. my code:

```
 public void createNewSoundPool(Context context, int value){
   AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
           .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
           .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
           .build();
    soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
           .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
            .setMaxStreams(10)
           .build();
    if(value==1) {
       soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {               @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded= true;
            }
       });
        soundIds[0] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.one, 1);
        soundIds[5] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.stick, 6);
        soundIds[3] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.loss, 4);
        soundIds[4] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.win, 5);
    }

 if(loaded==true) {
        if (value == 1) {
            soundPool.play(soundIds[0], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        }

     if(value==2){
        soundPool.play(soundIds[1],1,1,1,0,1);
    }else if(value==3){
        soundPool.play(soundIds[2],1,1,1,0,1);
    }else if(value==4){
        soundPool.play(soundIds[3],1,1,1,0,1);
    }else if(value==5){
        soundPool.play(soundIds[4],1,1,1,0,1);
    }else if(value==6){
        soundPool.play(soundIds[5],1,1,1,0,1);
    }else if(value==7){
        soundPool.play(soundIds[6],1,1,1,0,1);
    }else if(value==8){
        soundPool.play(soundIds[7],1,1,1,0,1);
    }
```

i have multiple levels with different sounds  but not more than 4 sound in one level.
sound are played using  if else by there value.

similar codes is for soundpool deprecated and it's working

Comment: i checked and log.i show that all 4 sound where loaded but still no sound. and in logcat says that sample not READY

Answer (score 0):

You've loaded the multiple sound file, so you need to wait until all the sound file gets loaded in soundpool.

```
// Load files first
soundIds[0] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.one, 1);
soundIds[5] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.stick, 6);
soundIds[3] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.loss, 4);
soundIds[4] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.win, 5);

loaded = false;
final int lastLoadedId = soundIds[4];

//Then wait for the onLoadComplete event
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() 
{               
      @Override
      public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) 
      {
        if(sampleId == lastLoadedId)
        {
            loaded= true;
        }
        // May be you want to add log here to see the IDs of the items loaded
      }
});
```

Comment: At first I was tried to check the loaded state of each sound file using an array, but then I noticed that the `soundIds[]` isn't arranged in-order, which makes it difficult to track back the index (array) of each item. If possible fix the arrangement of `soundIds[]` and make the `loaded[]` as an array to check the loaded state. The above code may not work if the `soundIds[4]` triggered the `setOnLoadComplete` before the other items does.